# Use Tab as delimiter and at a empty line start a new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, import

I have a script to import text files into Excel.

**Goal** is to use Tab as delimiter and at a empty line, start a new worksheet.

**Problem** currently the script starts a new sheet for every line.

Do I need to use a different way to interpret empty lines? Other attempts that interpret and handle the sheet change successfully, strip spaces from the data on import and then the delimiter is ineffective.

```
Public Sub ImportTextFile(FName As String, Sep As String)

Dim RowNdx As Long
Dim ColNdx As Integer
Dim TempVal As Variant
Dim WholeLine As String
Dim Pos As Integer
Dim NextPos As Integer
Dim SaveColNdx As Integer
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim SheetNumber As Long

Const C_START_SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1"
SheetNumber = 1
RowNdx = C_START_ROW_FIRST_PAGE
Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(C_START_SHEET_NAME)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
SaveColNdx = ActiveCell.Column
RowNdx = ActiveCell.Row

Open FName For Input Access Read As #1

While Not EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, WholeLine
    'This section added to create new sheets for empty lines
    If InputLine = "" Then
           SheetNumber = SheetNumber + 1
           Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(after:=WS)
           RowNdx = 1
    End If

    If Right(WholeLine, 1) <> Sep Then
        WholeLine = WholeLine & Sep
    End If
    ColNdx = SaveColNdx
    Pos = 1
    NextPos = InStr(Pos, WholeLine, Sep)
    While NextPos >= 1
        TempVal = Mid(WholeLine, Pos, NextPos - Pos)
        Cells(RowNdx, ColNdx).Value = TempVal
        Pos = NextPos + 1
        ColNdx = ColNdx + 1
        NextPos = InStr(Pos, WholeLine, Sep)
    Wend
    RowNdx = RowNdx + 1
    SheetNumber = SheetNumber + 1
Wend

EndMacro:
On Error GoTo 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Close #1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading into`WholeLine`, then testing `InputLine`

Adding `Option Explicit` would catch things like this.